# Scrollable screenshot using ashot in selenium not working with internet explorer 11 version but working fine in chrome and firefox

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11, screenshot, ashot

```
    public static void takeScrollableScreenshot(WebDriver webdriver, String filePath, WebDriverWait wait) throws Exception
      {
    File myDirectory = new File(filePath);
    if(!myDirectory.exists()) {
       myDirectory.mkdirs(); 
    }else{
       // Directory already exist
    }

    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(500))
            .takeScreenshot(webdriver);

    ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "PNG", myDirectory);

}
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNgds.png)

Comment: what error are you getting. I am using IE11 and it is working fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method to take full page screenshot in IE :

```
/**
     * @param driver
     * @param file e.g "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\RegressionTests\\oracle.png"
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String file) throws IOException {
         ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
         File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
         FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(file));
     }
```

Hope that helps you:)

Comment: it is scrolling to bottom of the page and taking the screenshot but i need the screenshot of entire page

Comment: it will take the screenshot of entire page

Comment: check the image after screenshot has been taken

Comment: if you remove the JavascriptExecutor code then also it will work and will capture the whole page screenshot (in IE only), for other browsers we use Ashot

Comment: have you checked that.

Comment: @dangi13 nah... it didnt work, it still takes a screenshot merely of the viewport